Speed up memory allocation
We have some servers CentOS 7 with 1Tb RAM for large math calculation.
When server is just rebooted, at application start memory allocation is realy fast

When some calculations were already performed on the server (large uptime) (more then 3 hour required for memory allocation)

Strace log  fullfilled with brk and sched_yield
brk
brk
brk
brk
....
sched_yield
sched_yield
brk
....

Sysctl: vm.swappiness = 1
Monitoring show that swap not used during memory allocation.
Is it possible to speed up memory allocation for application with some system tuning?

Does the allocation use huge pages?

The easiest ways to speed up memory allocation will all involve changing the way the allocation is performed; 3 hours for a single allocation is far too much.


Does the allocation use huge pages?
I dont know. How to understand this?
changing the way the allocation is performed;
How to change this?


Well, the first step is looking at the code for the application; how specifically does it allocate its half-gigabyte of memory?
To find out about huge pages, you can read up online; I suspect though that it either is, and your memory is very fragmented, or isnt, and your algorithm is bad.

This is vendor's application, we have no access to source code and no access to support. I have only strace output at the moment when application allocating memory.

If no access to support, then maybe you need a script that shuts down gracefully and then forces a reboot. In a corporate environment, a scripted reboot will likely be flagged as a security risk, so you'll need to gather a well reasoned set of evidence to prove that this is business critical.  OR that they have to start paying for support AND that they can then wait for the vendor to provide a solution. Maybe there is a "maverick" manager above you that understands the problem and is willing to make the argument for your case.

If you can figure out how it is allocating that memory, (eg, via libc), it might be possible to use debugging tools to allocate said memory using a faster technique (one which doesn't involve what seems to be a tight loop of outdated system calls allocating the memory one page at a time).
Other tips include swapping out the libc that this program for a newer one, or looking into memory fragmentation
